# pass data in tableViewCell to another VC failed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know it's kinda frequently ask question, but I did some research and none of the solutions work.

so here's my controller with table view

```
class MainPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, YoubikeManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let mainPageCell = MainPageCell()
let mapPage = MapViewController()

var stations: [Station] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
     }
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "infoCell") as! MainPageCell
    cell.stationNameLabel.text = stations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.stationLocationLabel.text = stations[indexPath.row].address
    cell.numberOfRemainingBikeLabel.text = stations[indexPath.row].numberOfRemainingBikes
    cell.printer = stations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.mapBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.mapBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveToMapPage), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
func moveToMapPage(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMap", sender: self)
    let nameToPass = stations[sender.tag].name
    mapPage.stationName = nameToPass
}
```

}

there is a UIButton in my tableView cell

```
class MainPageCell: UITableViewCell {
var printer: String!
let mapPage = MapViewController()
@IBOutlet weak var stationNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mapBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stationLocationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfRemainingBikeLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    mapBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

}
func mapBtnTapped (sender: UIButton) {
        print (printer)

}
}
```

and this is my other vc

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var stationName: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = stationName
}
```

}

I will elaborate my problem that i am now facing here !
the thing I want to do is when I tap the button in tableView cell, I want to go to MapViewController and make the title of this vc "the station name" in the same cell.

so in VC with tableView, in  `cellforRowAt` function I called addTarget.
with `moveToMapPage` function

but when I tapped the button and goes to MapView VC, the `stationName` is still nil

I have no clue what goes wrong, 
any hints are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapPage` is **not** the instance that you are navigating to, so you're setting a variable on an unrelated controller.

You need to use `prepare(for segue...` if you want to get a link to the new controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    // if you have multiple segues, you can set up different actions for each
    if segue.identifier == "segueToMap"
    {
        let mapPage : MapViewController = segue.destination as! MapViewController

        let mapPage : MapViewController = segue.destination as! MapViewController
        mapPage.stationName = nameToPass
        mapPage.delegate = self // if required
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hey Russell thanks for answering! seems I misunderstood the navigation stuff

Answer (score 1):

use navigation controller

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"toMap") as! toMapViewController
 vc.stationNam = stations[sender.tag].name
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```